# Django aggregate calculating incorrectly because of many-to-many join in queryset

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

We have a model with a many-to-many relationship with another model, and doing a Sum aggregation on it seems to multiply the result by the number of many-to-many relationships. Example models below:

```
class Attendee(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()
  category = models.TextField()

class Event(models.Model):
  start_date = models.DateTimeField()
  end_date = models.DateTimeField()
  attendees = models.ManyToManyField(Attendee, related_name="event")

class CalendarEvent(models.Model):
  calendar = models.TextField()
  event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name="calendar_events")
```

We filter out some records based on Attendee, and then aggregate the duration of the events.

```
queryset = queryset.filter(event__attendee__category="Accountant")

queryset = queryset.annotate(duration=models.ExpressionWrapper(
  models.F('event__end_date') - models.F('event__start_date'), 
  output_field=models.fields.DurationField()
))
```

Whenever we run the aggregation at the end, all `duration` values would be multiplied by the number of Attendees associated with the Event/CalendarEvent. For example, if the event is 15 minutes long and has 4 attendees, we would expect the duration to be 900 seconds, but instead it's 3600 seconds. We noticed in the raw PSQL query that there is a LEFT OUTER JOIN against Attendees, so we tried removing the Attendee filter and it gave us the proper data.

Is there any way to aggregate across a relationship like this without the joined results getting mixed in?